# Run sas script if do not fit condition

Tags: sas

I would like to check whether a data set exist in the work library. If not i need to import it from local drive `C:\w5`

```
libname yin "C:\w5";
data _null_;
    dsname = "work.base11";
    if exist(dsname, "DATA") then
        put 'data set do exist';
    else %include 'C:\testing.sas';
run;
```

For the `testing.sas` script

```
libname yin "C:\w5";    
data work.base11;
    set yin.base11;
run;
```

With error:

```
ERROR: Statement is not valid or it is used out of proper order.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing with SAS is that you cannot write `Proc` step inside the `data` step and vice versa, that is why you are getting the error, below could be the quick and easy way to check and import.

```
%macro check_n_import();

%if %sysfunc(exist(work.base11)) = 0 %then %do;
libname yin "C:\w5";    
data work.base11;
    set yin.base11;
run;
%end;   

%mend;

%check_n_import;
```

Comment: Hi again @NEOmen, it work like a champ. What if i want to include a instream data?

Comment: where do you want to include it?

Comment: inside the do loop. It seems that i can employe call execute to do this task.

Comment: I did not get it! What do you want to do?